# Vue.http.interceptors.push undefined is not an objec

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I want do logouts and redirect to login page when server return error 401 in my Vue app but in my console I see error: "Cannot read property 'interceptors' of undefined". Have you any idea how fix that?

```
import router from './router/router.js'
import Vue from 'vue'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import Vuelidate from 'vuelidate'


Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
Vue.use(Vuelidate)

Vue.http.interceptors.push(function (request, next) {
    next(function (response) {
      if (response.status === 401) {
        let msg = response.body.returnMessage
        localStorage.setItem('logoutReason', msg)
      }
    })
  })

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now everything working good ;)

Answer (score 1):

According his [documentation](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/develop/docs/config.md) you should first install `vue-resourse` as dependency then use it as `import VueResource from 'vue-resource';` & `Vue.use(VueResource);`